# как отредактировать форму товара в админке wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: подскажите какой файл нужно редактировать чтоб можно было добавить ещё два поля URL товара, и чтоб кнопка на странице товаров была не просто КУПИТЬ а КУПИТЬ с выпадающим списком в котором будут з ссылки на товары партнеров]
подскажите какой файл нужно редактировать чтоб можно было добавить ещё два поля URL товара, и чтоб кнопка на странице товаров была не просто КУПИТЬ а КУПИТЬ с выпадающим списком в котором будут  ссылки на товары партнеров

Comment: Никакой файл. [Ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). И две совершенно разные задачи

Comment: хорошо, какой файл нужно ортедактировать чтоб просто добавить ещё 2 дополнительных поля к уже существующему полю URL товара

Comment: @ivanivanenko как Вам и написали сверху, никакой файл. Это так не работает, то что Вы отредактируете в файле, слетит при следующем же обновлении и в принципе в WordPress так никто не делает. Для этого есть хуки, потому используйте либо хуки, по типу `woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data`, либо плагины, которые добавляют эти самые кастом филды.